# No app selection list for some file types

Tags: windows-10-mobile

When opening some file types, I don't see an app selection list and the default (Microsoft) app starts automatically. For example, for opening MKV files, I have two apps, Microsoft Videos and Movies, and VLC Player. However, when I open and MKV file, Videos and Movies starts automatically, without asking me what app to use, and I don't like that because the default Windows app has problems playing MKV files. Can I do something to force Windows Mobile to always show the app selection menu or set a default app?